# Unable to trigger web request implemented in Giraffe

Tags: http, f#, visual-studio-code, postman

I'm struggling to trigger a web service that's written in Giraffe.

Here's the code:

```
let webApp : HttpContext -> HttpHandlerResult = 

    choose [
        GET >=>
            choose [ routef "/platforms/" fetchPlatforms ]
```

fetchPlatforms is implemented as follows:

```
let private fetchPlatforms () (context : HttpContext) =
    async { let response = getPlatforms()
            return! json response context
    }
```

The issue that I'm running into is that when I run the server code and then attempt to test the web service, I get the following message:

[image]

Here's the entire [solution](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/tree/master/Server).

**Update:**

I am only observing this issue in VS Code.

Hence, I can observe a successful web request and response using Visual Studio 2017 (3) version 15.4

Here's the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2952vnPXmE) that demonstrates the difference between VS2017 and VS Code

Comment: What if you add the trailing slash? You have it defined in the route, and I think routes are just a string match

Comment: I tried adding a trailing slash. No difference.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOuytOfHUTE

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded your source code and tried to reproduce the issue, but first I was getting an error during startup because I don't have your db configured locally, therefore I made the following change:

```
type TestObj =
    {
        Prop1 : string
        Prop2 : int
    }

let private fetchPlatforms  =
    let obj1 = { Prop1 = "test"; Prop2 = 100 }
    json obj1
    //  let response = getPlatforms()
    //  json response
```

... and when I start the app now and make a Postman call to the `/platforms` endpoint then it seems to work fine for me...

[image: postman]

Have you resolved your issue perhaps?

Comment: Nope. My YouTube service works but not the platforms request.

Comment: I noticed that on your body tab, your type is set to "json". However, mine is set  to "text". When I attempt to set mine to "json", I get the error: "Unexpected 'N'"

Comment: I also noticed that your screenshot has 2 headers where mine has zero.

Comment: Here's a video that I did describing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOuytOfHUTE

Comment: Hi Scott Nimrod, just wanted to let you know that I tried to watch your video now but to be honest I am away from home at the moment and where I am we had a storm and I am sitting soaked in a hotel lobby with really bad wifi at the moment. I am going to a different place tomorrow and then I should have good internet and plenty of time to look at your project again and hopefully help you to get it fixed. Long story short, sorry for not being able to help you quicker now, and it's not that I forgot about it! :/

Comment: Wow. Thanks for taking me into consideration. I'm attending the Software Craftsmanship Conference in London. So I'm not in a hurry. Thanks again.

Comment: Added a bounty to this as a result of me still wanting to use your framework

Comment: @dustinmoris Did you ever get a chance to look at this?

Answer (score 2):

routef should match pattern:
https://github.com/dustinmoris/Giraffe#routef

otherwise try route:

```
let webApp : HttpContext -> HttpHandlerResult = 

choose [
    GET >=>
        choose [ route "/platforms" >=> fetchPlatforms ]
```

EDIT:

And looking at your code, the *fetchPlatforms* function is not a proper handler.
[HttpHandler](https://github.com/dustinmoris/Giraffe#httphandler) :

> A HttpHandler is a simple function which takes two curried arguments, a HttpFunc and a HttpContext, and returns a HttpContext (wrapped in an option and Task workflow) when finished.

Instead of:

```
let private fetchPlatforms  =
     let response = getPlatforms()
     json response
```

Try something like that:

```
let fetchPlatforms   =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
        let response = getPlatforms()
        json response next ctx
```

You can do that async as well (it depends on *getPlatforms*):

```
let fetchPlatforms   =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
        task {
            let! response = getPlatforms()
            return! json response next ctx
        }
```

Comment: Thx. But still no luck.